# Passing argument from a list

Tags: python, django, list

I have a function that I'm using and I need to pass it a list of arguments, however, it gives an error when I try to pass the list because it can't hash.

The function in question here is the values() method on a Django Queryset, but I think this is a more general python question.

So I have:

```
values_list = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
models.MyModel.objects.values(values_list).all()
```

This gives an error `unhashable type: 'list'`  when i try to run the code.
Assuming that I can't alter the values method, how can I add this list to the arguments list in the normal manner?

```
for arg in values_list:
  queryset = MyModel.objects.values(arg)
```

Answer (score 8):

you need to use [list unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
models.MyModel.objects.values(*values_list).all()
```

(note the asterisk)

Answer (score 0):

can you use a tuple instead of a list? a tuple is hashable.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to make values_list as a tuple instead of a list, but if you can't alter the values method, then list unpacking is the way to go.